# What's the difference between "total coverage" and "code coverage" in rcov?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, code-coverage, rcov

When rcov generates a report, it shows "total coverage" and "code coverage" for each file.  What's the difference between the two metrics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://www.rubydoc.info/github/relevance/rcov/master/Rcov/FileStatistics

**total_coverage** is:

> Total coverage rate if comments are also considered "executable",
>   given as a fraction

**code_coverage** is:

> Code coverage rate: fraction of lines of code executed, relative to
>   the total amount of lines of code (loc).

Unless a project's comments are considered executable, the most valuable metric will be "code coverage".